# Ubuntu 18.04: Tomcat 8.5 webapp and lib folder location

Tags: 18.04, tomcat8

With `apt` I've installed the tomcat8 package for Ubuntu Server 18.04.
I've read [this Q/A already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37548877/2243745).

The default path in `$CATALINA_HOME` is `/usr/share/tomcat8/`.
There is no folder "webapps". But in `/var/lib/tomcat8/` is one.
Both folders have a subfolder `lib`.
Tomcat's default app is place in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`.
I've found some nice explanations for the catalina.home vs catalina.base question. But they didn't make it clear to me, how Ubuntu's configuration should be used.

Where should I place my webapps if I use a single instance of Tomcat only?

Answer (score 3):

You can get to know this by listing all paths installed by apt using

`dpkg -L tomcat8 | grep webapp`

The result shows

`/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`